# C++ Primitive Type Initialization v.s. Object Initialization

Tags: c++, oop, object, initialization, primitive-types

I'm curious of how C++ primitive built in types, int for instance, are initialized in comparison to objects of a class.

After doing research I learned that C++ is a statically typed language meaning type checking is done at compile-time not run-time. This means, that primitive types are **not** objects of a class and a types cannot change.

So what differs in the following object initializations:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int num;
    Foo(int n) : num(n) {}
};

Foo bar(5);
Foo bar2{ 5 };
Foo bar3 = 5;
```

To the primitive initializations:

```
int num(5);
int num2{ 5 };
int num3 = 5;
```

I know instances of Foo call the constructor to initialize but what does the primitive call or do to initialize if it is not an object?

Furthermore what else fundamentally distinguishes the types Foo & int, other than Foo being "a user defined blue print to create instances" and int being "a non object built in type".

Comment: Perhaps [this initialization reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) might be helpful?

Comment: Regarding _what else fundamentally distinguishes the types Foo & int_, I made a similar [sample on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/RB9qTy) and played a bit with `-O0` (no optimization) vs. `-O2` ("significant" optimization). With the latter, the generated code for `int n = a;` was optimized away and `Foo bar(b);` was just a single `movl` - IMHO not much difference. (The I/O was introduced to have side-effects which prevent optimizing everything away.)

Comment: ...but there might be significant differences at compile-time. E.g. applying arithmetic operators to `Foo` not possible (without overloading) or [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral).

Comment: There are various rules of the language that differ for class types and non-class types (too broad to give an exhaustive list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Class initialization

For a class with user-defined constructors like `Foo`, the only difference between the initializations is that the last (called *copy-initialization*) is equivalent to

```
Foo bar3 = Foo(5);
```

That is, the initializer expression is converted to the class type (*via* a constructor) and then `bar3` is initialized from *that*.  (Until C++17 this notionally involves a copy or move, but compilers routinely avoid that overhead.)

Note that there is one more syntax:

```
Foo bar4={5};
```

This is known as *copy-list-initialization*, but the only difference from the version without the `=` is that `explicit` constructors are disallowed.

## Structural initialization

The lack of significant differences between these forms fails to motivate having them and is therefore confusing.  The distinction comes with *containers*, broadly construed so as to include *aggregates* (simple C-like `struct`s).  Those support `{}`-initialization with a different meaning, which is to construct an object *containing* some data, rather than *computed* from it.  So

```
std::vector<double> a(10,1),b{10,1};
```

defines `a` to have 10 values (which are each 1) and `b` to have the two values 10 and 1.

It has been suggested that use of braces to initialize should be restricted to this meaning to avoid confusion.

## Primitive initialization

Finally, we have your `int` examples.  It should be clear now that all the initializations are interchangeable (except that *list-initialization* prohibits narrowing conversions), since there is no distinction between computing a primitive value and filling it.  Nor is there any possibility of observing the initialization of (or assignment to) a variable of primitive type: it simply comes to have the value supplied as an atomic action of the abstract machine.  (Compilers know this and elide as many such variables as they can for efficiency.)

## Objects

Even an `int` is an object (in the C++ sense of that word, not the Java or Python sense), and when you have a `Foo` you have two objects: the `Foo` itself and the `int num` it contains (which is created and destroyed along with it).  So your initializations of `Foo` objects are also two initializations each: the outer one *consisting of* the inner one (which is always performed by the `num(n)` *member-initializer*).

It is the existence of this extra object that distinguishes `Foo` from `int`, without having to define a class operationally in terms of a memory layout: the operations allowed on a `Foo` are in general different because it is *distinct* from any object(s) it might contain.